# How to get return value !=0 out of Django shell in case of error

Tags: python, django, shell, exception, django-1.8

Is there a way to get an error code != 0 from Django shell when experiencing some issue e.g. an uncatched exception inside?

So imagine something like that:

```
echo "
from django.contrib.auth.models import User;
User.objects.create_superuser('admin', 'root@localhost',
 'secure_me')" | ./manage.py shell
```

will cause an exception, if the user admin is already existing. Unfortunately it's even in such a case a return code of 0.

Answer (score 2):

As a possible workaround, you can write custom [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/) which accepts whatever you want and returns any code you want.